# Refactoring class to make it injectable/mockable

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

I am really struggling to properly refactor my class so I can inject it.
This is the class I am talking about:

```
internal class OCRService : IDisposable, IOCRService
{
    private const TextRecognitionMode RecognitionMode = TextRecognitionMode.Handwritten;
    private readonly ComputerVisionClient _client;

    public OCRService(string apiKey)
    {
        _client = new ComputerVisionClient(new ApiKeyServiceClientCredentials(apiKey))
        {
            Endpoint = "https://westeurope.api.cognitive.microsoft.com"
        };
    }

    public async Task<List<Line>> ExtractTextAsync(byte[] image)
    {
        //Logic with _client here
    }
}
```

I really don't know where to Initialize the ComputerVisionClient. I am thinking of the following options:

- Make `ComputerVisionClient` a public property which can be set after injecting.
- Putting the apikey in a config file and then read it in the constructor.

The problem is that I want to mock this service but when I mock it it still calls the constructor which connects to the ComputerVisionClient.

Comment: Does `ComputerVisionClient` have a backing abstraction?  Even if it does not you could just inject `ComputerVisionClient` as a constructor arg.  The `apiKey` should be part of a `IOCRServiceConfiguration` abstraction and injected in

Comment: ComputerVisionClient is part of an azure Nuget package.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the rest of your architecture, you have a few options.  The simplest is to inject the `ComputerVisionClient` (or `IComputerVisionClient` if you can create one) into the constructor, and mock it in your tests.

```
public class OCRService : IOCRService, IDisposable
{
    public OCRService(IComputerVisionClient client)
    {
        _client = client;
    }
}
```

If, for some reason, you must create the client in the constructor, you can create a factory and inject that:

```
internal class ComputerVisionClientFactory : IComputerVisionClientFactory
{
    public GetClient(string apiKey)
    {
        return new ComputerVisionClient(new ApiKeyServiceClientCredentials(apiKey))
        {
            Endpoint = "https://westeurope.api.cognitive.microsoft.com"
        };
    }
}

// ...
internal class OCRService : IOCRService, IDisposable
{
    public OCRService(string apiKey, IComputerVisionClientFactory clientFactory)
    {
        _client = clientFactory.GetClient(apiKey);
    }
}
```

As @maccettura suggested, you can also further abstract away the `apiKey` by creating an `IOCRServiceConfiguration` that contains the logic for getting the key, and pass that into the constructor for either `OCRService` or `ComputerVisionFactory`, depending on your architecture.  Naively:

```
internal class OCRServiceConfiguration : IOCRServiceConfiguration
{
    public OCRServiceConfiguration(string apiKey)
    {
        ApiKey = apiKey;
    }

    public string ApiKey { get; }
}
```

Comment: In case of injecting with interfaces. Where do I set the api key?

Comment: You have several options there, too, depending on where it's coming from.  You could use the `OCRServiceConfiguration` option that knows how to get it (from a config file, or maybe a database), or you could do it in your IoC configuration.  These options are really just moving things around to make it testable, so somewhere, the api key is going to get retrieved and inserted.

Comment: The question is "Do you know the api key during compile time? (configuration files or hardcoded key) If so - inject it as Configuration. If you know your api key only during runtime then you need to create a factory class which will be responsible to load a key and provide to consumer of the key

Comment: I Implemented it at the injection like this right now: `services.AddSingleton<IComputerVisionClient>(provider => new ComputerVisionClient(new ApiKeyServiceClientCredentials(Configuration.GetSection("APIKeys").Get<ApiKeysOptions>().OCRKey)));` is that correct?